# Take picture from local video source and submit via PHP form

Tags: php, html, flash

How would I go about taking a picture from a video capture card or webcam?  Should I use flash to do this?  I want to submit the picture via a php form and upload it to my webserver and place a link to it in my MySQL database.  Is there a flash app already built that I can use to perform this?

Comment: Its a bit confusing what you are trying to achieve here. Why do you need to upload the image using a an PHP form? Why do you need to store a link to it in a mysql database? Where is the code running? Where is the webcam? How frequently do you want to refresh the image? What operating system(s) do these run on? Have you got software which you can use to capture an image from the webcam? Should this be done manually or do you want it to run automatically?

Comment: I just need the client-side app that takes a pic and stores it via a form.  It also needs to be in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/